# Spreadsheet Formula, return the row whose range matches a value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have the data table below, and I want that given a value 'x' look in 'A' and get the lower value in 'B'.

For instance 10.000 should return 0, 38.000 should return 7,8 and 900.000 should return 20. In my locale '.' means thousand separator and ',' is for decimals.

If possible I would like a formula which works in excel and gdocs. Thanks.

```
 A          B
 0          0
 37.500,01  7,8
 45.000,01  9,1
 58.345,62  11,4
 120.206,02 13,6
 208.075,91 15,7
 295.242,83 17,2
 382.409,77 18,2
 600.000,01 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about gdocs but in excel try the following.

```
=vlookup(value ; $A$1:$B$9 ; 2 ; 1)
```

where `value` is the value you are searching for.

The only prerequisite is that column `A` must be sorted in ascending order, as you have in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LOOKUP` function, assuming lookup value in C2 use this formula in D2

`=LOOKUP(C2,A$1:B$9)`

Comment: @pnuts - Thanks - I included a typo just to test you! - of course the "lookup table" needs to include column B, now corrected

Comment: Thanks AHC for suggested edit - your version works and can be better in some circumstances but I prefer the more compact version

Answer (score 0):

The following would work for your needs:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(38,A:A,1),1)
```

Where `38` is the value we are looking up. Match will look in `A:A` and return the row where the value is less than `38` (because the third parameter of the `match()` formula is `1`).

The Index will return the row in `B:B` that `Match()` just outputted.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for 900,000 you're hoping to return the value from 600,000.01, because that's the last value it is higher than.

You can do this with an array formula, but I prefer to make Index do that work for me. As such, I present INDEX/MATCH/INDEX:

First, sort your data in A Largest to Smallest.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$9,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(900000>$A$1:$A$9,0),0))
```

You can change 900,000 to whichever number you're looking for, or reference a cell with the value in it.

The second INDEX, the one nested in there, is examining each cell in Col A to determine if your target value is greater than them. It creates an array of TRUE's and FALSE's.

Next, you use MATCH to find the first TRUE in that array you created. That's the position of the first cell that your target is greater than (this is why we sort largest to smallest).

Once we know how far down the list it is, we use the first INDEX to look that far down Col B and grab the info you're looking for!

Play around with it, it makes sense once you think your way through it :) Good luck!